# Fortran Error: Unclassifed Statement in subroutines

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran90

New to Fortran here and I'm modifying some existing source code. I've defined all my variables and I think the math is correct but I'm still getting the following errors when compiling:

```
CPT_UD_lib_Curved.F90:68:2:

   ecrit = CSL_a - CSL_b * (P0 / 100.0) ** CSL_c
  1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
CPT_UD_lib_Curved.F90:118:2:

   ecrit_im = CSL_a - CSL_b * (Pimage(i) / 100.0) ** CSL_c
  1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
CPT_UD_lib_Curved.F90:174:4:

     ecrit = CSL_a - CSL_b * (Pval(i) / 100.0) ** CSL_c
    1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
CPT_UD_lib_Curved.F90:178:4:

     ecrit_im = CSL_a - CSL_b * (Pimage(i) / 100.0) ** CSL_c
    1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
```

I'm compiling using gfortran with MinGW. Here is some of my code:

```
SUBROUTINE InitState(CSL_a, CSL_b, CSL_c,Mcrit,Ncrit,Chi,Chi_im,            &
      Hy,H0,Hmod,psi,VoidRatio,OCR,Pval,Qval,Pimage,PimageOld,Dmin, &
      PimageMax,PsiImage,XH,Mitc,dilate,psi0,sigR0,sigT0,NumElem)
!----------------------------------------------------------------------------
! assign initial state values to each element
!----------------------------------------------------------------------------
!
 real, intent(out) :: Pval(:), Qval(:)
 real, intent(out) :: Pimage(:), PimageOld(:),PimageMax(:),Dmin(:)
 real, intent(out) :: psi(:), PsiImage(:), VoidRatio(:)
 real, intent(out) :: dilate(:), Mitc(:)
 real, intent(out) :: Hmod(:), XH(:)

 real :: Mcrit, Ncrit, Lambda_e, CSL_a, CSL_b, CSL_c, e0, Chi, Chi_im, Hmod0
 real :: Pimage0
 real :: SpacingRatio
 real :: ecrit

 real :: PimageOverP, PimageOverP_max, psi0
 real :: PsiImage0, Dmin0
 real :: H0, Hy
 real :: sigR0, sigT0, Q0, P0, Mitc0
 real :: eta0, dilate0
 real :: OCR 
 integer :: i, NumElem
!
  Q0 = sigR0 - sigT0
  P0 = (sigR0 + 2.0 * sigT0)/3.
  eta0=Q0/P0
!                General flow rule 
  Mitc0 = Mcrit - Ncrit*Chi*abs(psi0)
  SpacingRatio = exp(1.-eta0/Mitc0)
  PimageOverP = OCR / SpacingRatio
  PsiImage0 = psi0 + CSL_b * (PimageOverP / 100.0) ** CSL_c

!  repeat to get better PsiImage0 value

  Mitc0 = Mcrit - Ncrit*Chi_im*abs(PsiImage0)
  SpacingRatio = exp(1.-eta0/Mitc0)
  PimageOverP = OCR / SpacingRatio
  PsiImage0 = psi0 + CSL_b * (PimageOverP / 100.0) ** CSL_c

! now continue with the Pimage initial values

  PimageOverP_max = exp(-Chi_im * PsiImage0 / Mitc0) 
  Pimage0 = PimageOverP * P0

  Dmin0 = chi_im * PsiImage0 !* Mi0 / Mi_tc0

  dilate0 = Mitc0 *(log(P0) - log(Pimage0))
!
!      ***  current critical void ratio set to match chosen psi
  ecrit = CSL_a – CSL_b *(P0 / 100.0) ** CSL_c
  e0 = psi0 + ecrit

!       The 'in situ' hardening relation
  Hmod0 = set_H(H0, Hy, Psi0)
!
!       Now set initial values for all elements
!
  VoidRatio(:) = e0
  Hmod(:) = Hmod0
  Pval(:) = P0
  Qval(:) = Q0
!            current image state
  Pimage(:) = Pimage0
  PimageOld(:) = Pimage0
  PsiImage(:) = PsiImage0
  Dmin(:) = Dmin0
  psi(:) = psi0
  Mitc(:) = Mitc0
!            the flow rule
  dilate(:) = dilate0

  DO 1 i=1,NumElem
     PimageMax(i) = PimageOverP_max * P0         
     XH(i) = Hmod0 * Pval(i)/ PimageOld(i) * (PimageMax(i) - PimageOld(i))  
1 CONTINUE

  RETURN
END SUBROUTINE InitState

SUBROUTINE GNorSand (Pimage,Pnew,Qnew,fvalue,i, VoidRatio, depsV, CSL_a, CSL_b, CSL_c,  &
                    Mcrit, Ncrit, Chi_im)
! ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
! this function returns the measure of yield exceedence for triaxial
! compression behaviour of soil using the NorSand constitutive model
! F=0 is on yield surface, F<0 is elastic, F>0 is yielding
!
! NB: this is for loading and there are no checks for unloading/reloading
! ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
!
 real :: Pimage(:)
 real :: Qnew, Pnew
 integer :: i
 real, intent(out) :: fvalue
!
 real :: VoidRatio(:), depsV(:)
 real :: CSL_a, CSL_b, CSL_c, Mcrit, Ncrit, Chi_im
 real :: MitcNew, Void, ecrit_im, PsiIm

  Void = VoidRatio(i) - (1 + VoidRatio(i)) * depsV(i) 
  ecrit_im = CSL_a – CSL_b * (Pimage(i) / 100.0) ** CSL_c
  PsiIm = Void - ecrit_im
  MitcNew = Mcrit - Ncrit * Chi_im * abs(PsiIm)

  fvalue = Qnew - Pnew * MitcNew * (1. + log(Pimage(i)) - log(Pnew))

END SUBROUTINE GNorSand

SUBROUTINE UpdateState(CSL_a,CSL_b,CSL_c,Mcrit,Ncrit,Chi_im,Hy,H0,Hmod,                 &
      Pval,Qval,Pimage,PimageOld,Dmin,PimageMax,PsiImage,psi,Mitc,XH,dilate,VoidRatio,  &
      NumElem,depsV,sigmaR,sigmaT1,sigmaT2,sigmaRold,sigmaT1old,sigmaT2old)
!
  real :: sigmaR(0:), sigmaT1(0:), sigmaT2(0:), sigmaRold(0:), sigmaT1old(0:), sigmaT2old(0:)
  real :: Pval(:), Qval(:)
  real :: Pimage(:), PimageOld(:),PimageMax(:), Dmin(:)
  real :: VoidRatio(:), psi(:), PsiImage(:)
  real :: dilate(:), Mitc(:)
  real :: depsV(:)
  real :: Hmod(:), XH(:)

  real :: sigM, sigQ, Pold
  real :: Mcrit, Ncrit, Chi_im
  real :: CSL_a,CSL_b,CSL_c
  real :: H0, Hy
  real :: ecrit, ecrit_im
  real :: Psi_imO, PsiO
  real :: PsiIm
  real :: MitcOld, MiOld 
  real :: PimageMaxOld, PimageOverP_max
  real :: eta  

  integer NumElem
  integer i
!
  DO 1 i = 1, NumElem
    Psi_imO = PsiImage(i)
    PsiO = Psi(i)
    MitcOld = Mitc(i)
    MiOld = MitcOld
    PimageMaxOld = PimageMax(i)
    Pold = Pval(i)

!   now update all properties with the new stresses

    sigmaRold(i) = sigmaR(i) 
    sigmaT1old(i) = sigmaT1(i)
    sigmaT2old(i) = sigmaT2(i)
    sigM = (sigmaR(i) + sigmaT1(i) + sigmaT2(i)) / 3.0
    sigQ = sigmaR(i) - sigmaT1(i)

    Pval(i) = sigM
    Qval(i) = sigQ
    eta = sigQ/sigM
!  
    VoidRatio(i) = VoidRatio(i) - (1 + VoidRatio(i)) * depsV(i) 

    ecrit = CSL_a – CSL_b * (Pval(i) / 100.0) ** CSL_c
    psi(i) = VoidRatio(i) - ecrit              

!   PsiIm = e - e_crit @ Pimage
    ecrit_im = CSL_a – CSL_b * (Pimage(i) / 100.0) ** CSL_c
    PsiIm = VoidRatio(i) - ecrit_im
    Mitc(i) = Mcrit - Ncrit*Chi_im*abs(PsiIm)

    PsiImage(i) = PsiIm

    Mitc(i) = Mcrit - Ncrit*Chi_im*abs(PsiIm)
    PimageOverP_max = exp(-Chi_im * PsiIm/Mitc(i)) 
    PimageMax(i) =PimageOverP_max * Pval(i)

!    dilate(i) = Mitc(i) *(log(Pval(i)) - log(Pimage(i)))
    dilate(i) = Mitc(i) - eta  

    Hmod(i) = set_H(H0, Hy, Psi(i))             !linear
    XH(i) = Hmod(i) * Pval(i)/Pimage(i) * (PimageMax(i) - Pimage(i))

    PimageOld(i) = Pimage(i)

    Dmin(i) = chi_im * PsiImage(i) !* Mi0 / Mi_tc0

  1 CONTINUE
  RETURN
END SUBROUTINE UpdateState
```

Does anyone have an idea what this issue could be?

Comment: Welcome. Please do not use the snippet function, it is only for Javascript. Use the `{}` button for code.  Also, please also include the compiler command in all compiler error messages.

Comment: I concur and would like to ask for all the compiler flags.

Comment: @francescalus Uf, good catch. I would never be able to find that without trying the code. And even then I am not sure. They are indeed longer dashes, not minuses.

Comment: In my keyboard dash and minus sign are the same!!

Comment: @francescalus Good eyes !

Comment: Thanks M. Chinoune. The minus sign versus dash seemed to fix it and it compiled with no issues after. Thanks for looking at it.